# How to deploy a module/provider/spi via scripting?

Tags: wildfly, keycloak, jboss-cli

Is there a way to deploy modules to Wildfly **via scripting** (as in, without manually modifying XML files)? I know about the `jboss-cli.sh` command to `add module` but is there a way to either directly modify my `standalone.xml`/`domain.xml` or do some equivalent thing that will tell Wildfly to load the module?

---

Said another way...

I've discovered two ways to deploy modules:

1) Hot deploy a jar directly by copying it into `$KEYCLOAK_HOME/standalone/deployments`
   (Per the README in that directory, this method is **not recommended** for production deployments *but* it works without any manual work afterward.)

2) run `jboss-cli.sh --command="module add --name=com.example.MySpi"` then **manually** edit `standalone.xml` (or `domain.xml`) to have your module in the "providers" list, like so:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak-server:1.1">
  <web-context>auth</web-context>
  <providers>
    ...
    <provider>module:com.example.MySpi</provider>
  </providers>
  ...
</subsystem>
```

... and finally restart the server.

I'd like to use the recommended way, but without manually editing an XML file. Is there a recommended path for this?

Comment: Can you add more of the section the `<providers/>` tag is in or link to some documentation? More than likely you can add it via CLI with a management operation, but I'm not familiar with where that is located.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do something like

```
jboss-cli.sh --command="/subsystem=keycloak-server:list-add(name=providers, value=module:com.example.MySpi)"
```

Basically you can script everything that is in standalone.xml with jboss-cli. To find out more how your configuration looks internally, you may try `/subsystem=keycloak-server:read-resource(recursive=true)` within jboss-cli.

Comment: This command should update the standalone.xml automatically and therefore survive restarts.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, cannot add comments yet, so I'm adding this here.

I had to add the `--connect` option to the command above, otherwise it was complaining with `no connection to the controller`.

The whole command then would be:

`jboss-cli.sh --connect --command="/subsystem=keycloak-server:list-add(name=providers, value=module:com.example.MySpi)"`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @ieggel, and thanks for the addition! Hopefully the question helped you too!

Comment: Definitely helped me, as i was also searching for a way automatized way to register a provider module instead of manually modifying the XML file. Thanks !.

Comment: If you don't want to start the server you can use the [embedded wildfly server](https://www.wildfly.org/news/2017/10/10/Embedded-Host-Controller/) to edit `standalone.xml` without starting keycloak. Just run `embed-server --server-config=standalone.xml`

Comment: It seems to be blocked in the **docker** version.